# Is there any function Excel has that Google Sheets does not have?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have been using both lately and I was wondering if there is any function that works on Excel but does not work in Google Sheets or the other way around.

I tried using some functions on Exel that Google Sheets did not recognize.

Comment: `FILTERXML()`, `AGGREGATE()`, `DROP()`, `TAKE()`, `EXPAND()`, `TEXTSPLIT()`, `TEXTAFTER()`, `TEXTBEFORE()` these are excel formulas but not in google sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I have run a compare on [the list of Google Sheet functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) vs [the list of Excel functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188). There were some artefacts because (e.g.) search and searchb are listed as a single entry in Excel but separately in Google Sheets, but allowing for this I got this list of Excel functions which don't seem to be supported in Google Sheets:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Function Name       |                                                                                                                               Type and Description                                                                                                                               |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| AGGREGATE                | Math and trigonometry:    Returns an aggregate in a list or database                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| AMORDEGRC                | Financial:    Returns the depreciation for each accounting period by using a depreciation coefficient                                                                                                                                                                            |
| AREAS                    | Lookup and reference:    Returns the number of areas in a reference                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| ARRAYTOTEXT              | Text:    Returns an array of text values from any specified range                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| BAHTTEXT*                | Text:    Converts a number to text, using the ß (baht) currency format                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| BESSELI                  | Engineering:    Returns the modified Bessel function In(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| BESSELJ                  | Engineering:    Returns the Bessel function Jn(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| BESSELK                  | Engineering:    Returns the modified Bessel function Kn(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| BESSELY                  | Engineering:    Returns the Bessel function Yn(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| BINOM.DIST.RANGE*        | Statistical:    Returns the probability of a trial result using a binomial distribution                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| CALL                     | Add-in and Automation:    Calls a procedure in a dynamic link library or code resource                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| CUBEKPIMEMBER            | Cube:    Returns a key performance indicator (KPI) name, property, and measure, and displays the name and property in the cell. A KPI is a quantifiable measurement, such as monthly gross profit or quarterly employee turnover, used to monitor an organization's performance. |
| CUBEMEMBER               | Cube:    Returns a member or tuple in a cube hierarchy. Use to validate that the member or tuple exists in the cube.                                                                                                                                                             |
| CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY       | Cube:    Returns the value of a member property in the cube. Use to validate that a member name exists within the cube and to return the specified property for this member.                                                                                                     |
| CUBERANKEDMEMBER         | Cube:    Returns the nth, or ranked, member in a set. Use to return one or more elements in a set, such as the top sales performer or top 10 students.                                                                                                                           |
| CUBESET                  | Cube:    Defines a calculated set of members or tuples by sending a set expression to the cube on the server, which creates the set, and then returns that set to Microsoft Office Excel.                                                                                        |
| CUBESETCOUNT             | Cube:    Returns the number of items in a set.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| CUBEVALUE                | Cube:    Returns an aggregated value from a cube.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| DBCS                     | Text:    Changes half-width (single-byte) English letters or katakana within a character string to full-width (double-byte) characters                                                                                                                                           |
| DROP                     | Lookup and reference:    Excludes a specified number of rows or columns from the start or end of an array                                                                                                                                                                        |
| EUROCONVERT              | Add-in and Automation:    Converts a number to euros, converts a number from euros to a euro member currency, or converts a number from one euro member currency to another by using the euro as an intermediary (triangulation).                                                |
| EXPAND                   | Lookup and reference:    Expands or pads an array to specified row and column dimensions                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| FILTERXML                | Web:    Returns specific data from the XML content by using the specified XPath                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| FORECAST.ETS             | Statistical:    Returns a future value based on existing (historical) values by using the AAA version of the Exponential Smoothing (ETS) algorithm                                                                                                                               |
| FORECAST.ETS.CONFINT     | Statistical:    Returns a confidence interval for the forecast value at the specified target date                                                                                                                                                                                |
| FORECAST.ETS.SEASONALITY | Statistical:    Returns the length of the repetitive pattern Excel detects for the specified time series                                                                                                                                                                         |
| FORECAST.ETS.STAT        | Statistical:    Returns a statistical value as a result of time series forecasting                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| INFO                     | Information:    Returns information about the current operating environment                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| ISOMITTED                | Information:    Checks whether the value in a LAMBDA is missing and returns TRUE or FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                        |
| JIS                      | Text:    Changes half-width (single-byte) characters within a string to full-width (double-byte) characters                                                                                                                                                                      |
| NUMBERVALUE              | Text:    Converts text to number in a locale-independent manner                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| ODDFPRICE                | Financial:    Returns the price per $100 face value of a security with an odd first period                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| ODDFYIELD                | Financial:    Returns the yield of a security with an odd first period                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| ODDLPRICE                | Financial:    Returns the price per $100 face value of a security with an odd last period                                                                                                                                                                                        |
| ODDLYIELD                | Financial:    Returns the yield of a security with an odd last period                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| PHONETIC                 | Text:    Extracts the phonetic (furigana) characters from a text string                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| REGISTER.ID              | Add-in and Automation:    Returns the register ID of the specified dynamic link library (DLL) or code resource that has been previously registered                                                                                                                               |
| RTD                      | Lookup and reference:    Retrieves real-time data from a program that supports COM automation                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| SHEET                    | Information:    Returns the sheet number of the referenced sheet                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| SHEETS                   | Information:    Returns the number of sheets in a reference                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| SORTBY                   | Lookup and reference:    Sorts the contents of a range or array based on the values in a corresponding range or array                                                                                                                                                            |
| STOCKHISTORY             | Financial:    Retrieves historical data about a financial instrument                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| TAKE                     | Lookup and reference:    Returns a specified number of contiguous rows or columns from the start or end of an array                                                                                                                                                              |
| TEXTAFTER                | Text:    Returns text that occurs after given character or string                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| TEXTBEFORE               | Text:    Returns text that occurs before a given character or string                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| TEXTSPLIT                | Text:    Splits text strings by using column and row delimiters                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| VALUETOTEXT              | Text:    Returns text from any specified value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| WEBSERVICE               | Web:    Returns data from a web service.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| XMATCH*                  | Lookup and reference:    Returns the relative position of an item in an array or range of cells.                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Count of Excel functions (counting search, searchb etc. as a single entry) = 505 of which 49 do not appear on the Google list.

*Note*

I have starred (three at time of writing) functions which contributors have informed me *are* present in Google sheets, just not on the main listing page for Google Sheets functions.

Comment: Appreciate your use of markdown but there's a slight formatting problem, I think.

Comment: A thing of beauty!

Comment: *xmatch* sneaky sneeked into the list:>

Comment: Isn't that strange, I'm blowed if I can find it on the web page https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en#query= but sure enough it's available in GS.

Comment: its [there there](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049) but just not in the full list

Comment: also `BAHTTEXT` and `BINOM.DIST.RANGE` are available in Sheets.

Comment: Thank you. These appear to be two further functions which are not listed on the main page at https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en#query=binom so I will note them in my list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of Google Sheets functions which don't seem to be available in Excel (I'm submitting it as a separate answer because of space limitations):

```
+-------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Type     |       Name       |                                                  Syntax                                                   |                                                                        Description                                                                        |
+-------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator    | ADD              | ADD(value1, value2)                                                                                       | Returns the sum of two numbers. Equivalent to the `+` operator. Learn more                                                                                |
| Array       | ARRAY_CONSTRAIN  | ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(input_range, num_rows, num_cols)                                                          | Constrains an array result to a specified size. Learn more                                                                                                |
| Google      | ARRAYFORMULA     | ARRAYFORMULA(array_formula)                                                                               | Enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with arrays. Learn more |
| Statistical | AVERAGE.WEIGHTED | AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(values, weights, [additional values], [additional weights])                              | Finds the weighted average of a set of values, given the values and the corresponding weights. Learn more.                                                |
| Math        | COUNTUNIQUE      | COUNTUNIQUE(value1, [value2, ...])                                                                        | Counts the number of unique values in a list of specified values and ranges. Learn more                                                                   |
| Google      | DETECTLANGUAGE   | DETECTLANGUAGE(text_or_range)                                                                             | Identifies the language used in text within the specified range. Learn more                                                                               |
| Operator    | DIVIDE           | DIVIDE(dividend, divisor)                                                                                 | Returns one number divided by another. Equivalent to the `/` operator. Learn more                                                                         |
| Date        | EPOCHTODATE      | EPOCHTODATE(timestamp, [unit])                                                                            | Converts a Unix epoch timestamp in seconds, milliseconds, or microseconds to a datetime in UTC. Learn more                                                |
| Operator    | EQ               | EQ(value1, value2)                                                                                        | Returns `TRUE` if two specified values are equal and `FALSE` otherwise. Equivalent to the `=` operator. Learn more                                        |
| Array       | FLATTEN          | FLATTEN(range1,[range2,...])                                                                              | Flattens all the values from one or more ranges into a single column. Learn more                                                                          |
| Google      | GOOGLEFINANCE    | GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, [attribute], [start_date], [end_date|num_days], [interval])                         | Fetches current or historical securities information from Google Finance. Learn more                                                                      |
| Google      | GOOGLETRANSLATE  | GOOGLETRANSLATE(text, [source_language], [target_language])                                               | Translates text from one language into another Learn more                                                                                                 |
| Operator    | GT               | GT(value1, value2)                                                                                        | Returns `TRUE` if the first argument is strictly greater than the second, and `FALSE` otherwise. Equivalent to the `>` operator. Learn more               |
| Operator    | GTE              | GTE(value1, value2)                                                                                       | Returns `TRUE` if the first argument is greater than or equal to the second, and `FALSE` otherwise. Equivalent to the `>=` operator. Learn more           |
| Engineering | IMCOTH           | IMCOTH(number)                                                                                            | Returns the hyperbolic cotangent of the given complex number. For example, a given complex number "x+yi" returns "coth(x+yi)." Learn more.                |
| Engineering | IMLOG            | IMLOG(value, base)                                                                                        | Returns the logarithm of a complex number for a specified base. Learn more.                                                                               |
| Web         | IMPORTDATA       | IMPORTDATA(url)                                                                                           | Imports data at a given url in .csv (comma-separated value) or .tsv (tab-separated value) format. Learn more                                              |
| Web         | IMPORTFEED       | IMPORTFEED(url, [query], [headers], [num_items])                                                          | Imports a RSS or ATOM feed. Learn more                                                                                                                    |
| Web         | IMPORTHTML       | IMPORTHTML(url, query, index)                                                                             | Imports data from a table or list within an HTML page. Learn more                                                                                         |
| Web         | IMPORTRANGE      | IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)                                                                | Imports a range of cells from a specified spreadsheet. Learn more                                                                                         |
| Web         | IMPORTXML        | IMPORTXML(url, xpath_query)                                                                               | Imports data from any of various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds. Learn more                              |
| Engineering | IMTANH           | IMTANH(number)                                                                                            | Returns the hyperbolic tangent of the given complex number. For example, a given complex number "x+yi" returns "tanh(x+yi)." Learn more.                  |
| Operator    | ISBETWEEN        | ISBETWEEN(value_to_compare, lower_value, upper_value, lower_value_is_inclusive, upper_value_is_inclusive) | Checks whether a provided number is between two other numbers either inclusively or exclusively. Learn more                                               |
| Info        | ISDATE           | ISDATE(value)                                                                                             | Returns whether a value is a date. Learn more.                                                                                                            |
| Info        | ISEMAIL          | ISEMAIL(value)                                                                                            | Checks whether a value is a valid email address. Learn more                                                                                               |
| Web         | ISURL            | ISURL(value)                                                                                              | Checks whether a value is a valid URL. Learn more                                                                                                         |
| Text        | JOIN             | JOIN(delimiter, value_or_array1, [value_or_array2, ...])                                                  | Concatenates the elements of one or more one-dimensional arrays using a specified delimiter. Learn more                                                   |
| Operator    | LT               | LT(value1, value2)                                                                                        | Returns `TRUE` if the first argument is strictly less than the second, and `FALSE` otherwise. Equivalent to the `<` operator. Learn more                  |
| Operator    | LTE              | LTE(value1, value2)                                                                                       | Returns `TRUE` if the first argument is less than or equal to the second, and `FALSE` otherwise. Equivalent to the `<=` operator. Learn more              |
| Statistical | MARGINOFERROR    | MARGINOFERROR(range, confidence)                                                                          | Calculates the amount of random sampling error given a range of values and a confidence level. Learn more                                                 |
| Operator    | MINUS            | MINUS(value1, value2)                                                                                     | Returns the difference of two numbers. Equivalent to the `-` operator. Learn more                                                                         |
| Operator    | MULTIPLY         | MULTIPLY(factor1, factor2)                                                                                | Returns the product of two numbers. Equivalent to the `*` operator. Learn more                                                                            |
| Operator    | NE               | NE(value1, value2)                                                                                        | Returns `TRUE` if two specified values are not equal and `FALSE` otherwise. Equivalent to the `<>` operator. Learn more                                   |
| Operator    | POW              | POW(base, exponent)                                                                                       | Returns a number raised to a power. Learn more                                                                                                            |
| Google      | QUERY            | QUERY(data, query, [headers])                                                                             | Runs a Google Visualization API Query Language query across data. Learn more                                                                              |
| Text        | REGEXEXTRACT     | REGEXEXTRACT(text, regular_expression)                                                                    | Extracts matching substrings according to a regular expression. Learn more                                                                                |
| Text        | REGEXMATCH       | REGEXMATCH(text, regular_expression)                                                                      | Whether a piece of text matches a regular expression. Learn more                                                                                          |
| Text        | REGEXREPLACE     | REGEXREPLACE(text, regular_expression, replacement)                                                       | Replaces part of a text string with a different text string using regular expressions. Learn more                                                         |
| Filter      | SORTN            | SORTN(range, [n], [display_ties_mode], [sort_column1, is_ascending1], ...)                                | Returns the first n items in a data set after performing a sort. Learn more                                                                               |
| Google      | SPARKLINE        | SPARKLINE(data, [options])                                                                                | Creates a miniature chart contained within a single cell. Learn more                                                                                      |
| Text        | SPLIT            | SPLIT(text, delimiter, [split_by_each], [remove_empty_text])                                              | Divides text around a specified character or string, and puts each fragment into a separate cell in the row. Learn more                                   |
| Parser      | TO_DATE          | TO_DATE(value)                                                                                            | Converts a provided number to a date. Learn more                                                                                                          |
| Parser      | TO_DOLLARS       | TO_DOLLARS(value)                                                                                         | Converts a provided number to a dollar value. Learn more                                                                                                  |
| Parser      | TO_PERCENT       | TO_PERCENT(value)                                                                                         | Converts a provided number to a percentage. Learn more                                                                                                    |
| Parser      | TO_PURE_NUMBER   | TO_PURE_NUMBER(value)                                                                                     | Converts a provided date/time, percentage, currency or other formatted numeric value to a pure number without formatting. Learn more                      |
| Parser      | TO_TEXT          | TO_TEXT(value)                                                                                            | Converts a provided numeric value to a text value. Learn more                                                                                             |
| Operator    | UMINUS           | UMINUS(value)                                                                                             | Returns a number with the sign reversed. Learn more                                                                                                       |
| Operator    | UNARY_PERCENT    | UNARY_PERCENT(percentage)                                                                                 | Returns a value interpreted as a percentage; that is, `UNARY_PERCENT(100)` equals `1`. Learn more                                                         |
| Operator    | UPLUS            | UPLUS(value)                                                                                              | Returns a specified number, unchanged. Learn more                                                                                                         |
+-------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Count of Google functions (where search, searchb etc. are listed separately)= 513 of which again 49 do not appear on the Excel list.

There are seven functions like search & searchb which are paired on the Excel list but shown separately on the Google list.

Comment: feel [COUNTUNIQUEIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9584429?hl=en) will make the list: